# Face color attribute incorrectly applied

Tags: themes, faces

I want to modify the region's foreground regardless of syntax highlighting.

```elisp
(set-face-attribute 'region nil :foreground "#656555")
```

But this is what I get (see sample):

[image]

<kbd>C-u</kbd> <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>=</kbd> gives:

```
             position: 483 of 1807 (27%), column: 0
            character: ( (displayed as () (codepoint 40, #o50, #x28)
    preferred charset: ascii (ASCII (ISO646 IRV))
code point in charset: 0x28
               script: latin
               syntax: ()   which means: open, matches )
             category: .:Base, a:ASCII, l:Latin, r:Roman
             to input: type "C-x 8 RET HEX-CODEPOINT" or "C-x 8 RET NAME"
          buffer code: #x28
            file code: #x28 (encoded by coding system prefer-utf-8-unix)
              display: by this font (glyph code)
    mac-ct:-*-Monaco-normal-normal-normal-*-12-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1 (#x0B)

Character code properties: customize what to show
  name: LEFT PARENTHESIS
  old-name: OPENING PARENTHESIS
  general-category: Ps (Punctuation, Open)
  decomposition: (40) ('(')

There is an overlay here:
 From 483 to 623
  face                 region
  priority             (nil . 100)
  window               #<window 3 on init-theme.el>


There are text properties here:
  fontified            t
```

Comment: Is **#656555** equal to `zenburn/fg-1`?

Comment: Yes, sorry unclear.

Comment: Have you tried setting the `:background` to something like `'unspecified` so the `'default` font value gets inserted for that particular attribute?  *Apart from the values given below, each face attribute can have the value unspecified. This special value means that the face doesn't specify that attribute directly. An unspecified attribute tells Emacs to refer instead to a parent face (see the description :inherit attribute below); or, failing that, to an underlying face (see Displaying Faces). The default face must specify all attributes.*

Comment: Mmh, I can try. But the issue is the foreground here. The background is as I want it (unchanged). As you can see the sample has a black foreground instead of the specified `#656555`.

Comment: If a variable is a *face*, then the way you are trying won't work.  It *might* work if the variable is a color.

Comment: Mmh I don't follow. I've found `'region` with `helm-colors` then assumed I could change the foreground as I did for all other faces in the past. What do you mean by *If a variable is a face* ?

Comment: Whereas a color has just one value such as `#656555`, a face has multiple elements -- e.g., `(face-all-attributes 'region (selected-frame))` yields this output:  `"((:family . unspecified) (:foundry . unspecified) (:width . unspecified) (:height . unspecified) (:weight . unspecified) (:slant . unspecified) (:underline . unspecified) (:overline . unspecified) (:strike-through . unspecified) (:box . unspecified) (:inverse-video . unspecified) (:foreground . unspecified) (:background . ns_selection_bg_color) (:stipple . unspecified) (:inherit . unspecified))"`  A face can be assigned a variable.

Comment: I've used exactly the code in my post. No variable used.

Comment: What value(s) in the picture would you like to change, and what would you like that/those value(s) to be?  Or, do you have a syntax highlighting issue that you have not yet described in detail that is unrelated to the picture -- e.g., a particular major or minor mode that is causing a different color to appear than what you expect?

Comment: What I have set is correct (see attributes in the picture) the the sample (what I actually get in my buffers) isn't what I should get.

Comment: Select the region that is creating the unexpected result, and place your cursor at *the beginning* of the active region so that the unexpected result is to the *immediate* right of the cursor (if you use a vertical bar as a cursor) or at the precise location of the cursor (if you use a block / square for a cursor) -- then type `C-u C-x =`.  That will give you a list of all the faces and overlays at that location -- this should help give you a clue as to what other faces and/or overlays may be affecting the region highlighting.  An active `region` normally has a very high overlay priority.

Comment: I've updated my post, but it says there's only the `region` face :/.

Comment: Are you testing the region appearance in the ***same frame*** *where you evaluated the `set-face-attribute` sexp*? If not, there's your answer: you provided `nil` for the `FRAME` arg, which means change it only for the selected (i.e., current) frame. Otherwise, doing what you describe works for me - no problem.

Comment: Yes testing in the same buffer. Could it have something to do with the missing `--srgb` when using Emacs from http://emacsformacosx.com?

Comment: I would suggest trying a build via Homebrew, just for comparison.

Comment: Fyi I tested the same and got acceptable / expected behaviour.  Give us the version string from M-x version it might be helpful too.

Comment: @EmacsFodder `GNU Emacs 24.4.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0, NS apple-appkit-1265.21) of 2014-10-21 on builder10-9.porkrind.org` It works with other colors  from Zenburn palette (black'ish, and `#656555` only don't work).

Comment: Another idea would be to use `M-x list-colors-display` and choose the name of a color that is expressly supported -- e.g., `gray82` or `purple3` -- the corresponding numbers are to the far right.  There are 586 to choose from on an Emacs Trunk version built for OSX (--with-ns) as of October 2014.

Comment: @lawlist Yup I'm using another color as of now. It's just that I wanted to stay within the Zenburn palette. No big deal, I merely wanted to know what was causing such issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All 16777215 Hex colours should work on a properly configured build.

The command `M-x list-colors-display` is to help when selecting colours on a < 24bit display. (and to list *named* colours.)

The problem *appears to be* that the colour space that your EmacsForOSX Emacs.app bundle was built with is broken.

`#656555` just so happens to fall out of the space on this build.

On OSX I would recommend building with Homebrew and `--srgb`, ie.

```
brew install --cocoa --srgb emacs
```

Better yet use the Mac specific patch from Yamamoto Mitsuharu at Chiba University.

Xin Xu (@railwaycat) hosts a homebrew tap on github, so it's easier to install than applying the patch manually / and compiling. Just do this:

```
brew tap railwaycat/emacsmacport
brew install emacs-mac
```

#### A Quick note on Homebrew .app installs

The standard way that Homebrew installs `.app` bundles is to symlink them.  (using `brew linkapps`)

This is done because the Homebrew team (currently) wish to avoid touching the filesystem outside of `/usr/local` as much as possible.

Unfortunately this is problematic for users who rely on Spotlight to launch apps.  I'd hazard a guess that Emacs users would prefer this method as it's more keyboard centric.

It is possible to use an OSX "alias" instead of a symlink, these are indexed by Spotlight, although the ranking in results places "aliases" very low.  Yosemite's new Spotlight interface seems also to not show them under some conditions I haven't fully determined (I don't use Yosemite on any day-to-day machines, and it's being removed until at least Q4 2015 from some other machines I use, so I can't commit to testing this exhaustively.)

That said, there is no reason at all that the `.app` bundles should be located outside of `/Applications/` or `~/Applications/` so I strongly recommend simply moving the `Emacs.app` bundle there, just as you would if you were installing it from a `.dmg`.

Note that the Homebrew build will place other resources in the `/usr/local/Cellar/emacs` (or `emacs-mac`) folder.  This will not cause problems however.

---

See it working in these screenshots...

[image: eval in scratch]

[image: updated value shown in customize]

[image: selected region coloured as expected]

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer. Didn't know about Yamamoto Mitsuharu's version. I've seen the Cocoa one but I didn't like that fact that I couldn't find Emacs through the Spotlight search (links don't appear there).

Comment: Actually, that's just due to the way Homebrew installs .app packages.  The best way, without a doubt, is to `mv ` the Emacs.app into `/Applications/` and not symlink it. (Symlinks are not recognised/indexed by Spotlight.) - You can use a OSX Alias, which is like a symlink, which are indexed by Spotlight, however, they are relegated to low ranking in results, I've also noticed Yosemite won't even show them in the re-working of Spotlight.  So to re-iterate, **move** the Emacs.app into `/Applications/` for a happy, trouble-free time.

Comment: Ok thanks I thought of that but `cp`'ed to `/Users/angrybacon/Applications/`... By the way, what are the differences between `cocoa` and `railwaycat` ports ? **Edit:** nevermind, https://github.com/railwaycat/emacs-mac-port/blob/master/README-mac : )